# Joining multiple tables without conditioning the result to a single one / not missing any value... Full Outer Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, join, plsql

So let's say that I have four tables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Fr3.png)

I got this query:

```
SELECT 
    table1.mainValue, 
    table1.content1, 
    table2.content2, 
    table3.content3, 
    table4.content4
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
   ON table1.mainValue = table2.mainValue
FULL OUTER JOIN table3 
   ON table1.mainValue = table3.mainValue
FULL OUTER JOIN table4 
   ON table1.mainValue = table4.mainValue
```

And it is attaching all results to table1 because I am coding it that way but I am looking to not miss any of the mainValues in any of the tables bringing all the contents.

Is full outer join the answer to this?

I am not using a specific platform, only different ways to do it, so please, specify what platform your answer is based on.

Thank you!

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag correctly.

Comment: please don't use pictures.
insert the text and format is at code

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am not working on a specific Database, only seeking for ways to do it in different options.

Comment: @EstebanP. I tried but it's not getting the right format, so I am posting the picture while I figure out the correct format

Comment: @ManuellSandovall Use the following to generate a table with the desired results: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this with a `full outer join` but you need to be careful about missing `mainValues`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.mainValue, t2.mainvalue, t3.mainvalue, t4.mainvalue) as mainvalue,
       t1.content1, t2.content2, t3.content3, t3.content4
FROM table1 t1 FULL JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.mainValue = t1.mainValue FULL JOIN
     table3 t3
     ON table3.mainValue = COALESCE(t2.mainValue, t1.mainValue) FULL JOIN
     table4 t4
     ON t4.mainValue = COALESCE(t3.mainValue, t2.mainValue, t1.mainValue);
```

Another approach is `LEFT JOIN`, by combining all the main values into one query first:

```
SELECT mv.mainValue,
       t1.content1, t2.content2, t3.content3, t3.content4
FROM (SELECT t1.mainValue FROM table1 t1 UNION  -- intentional use of UNION to remove duplicates
      SELECT t2.mainValue FROM table2 t2 UNION
      SELECT t3.mainValue FROM table3 t3 UNION
      SELECT t4.mainValue FROM table4 t4
     ) mv LEFT JOIN
     table1 t1
     ON t1.mainValue = mv.mainValue
     table2 t2
     ON t2.mainValue = mv.mainValue LEFT JOIN
     table3 t3
     ON table3.mainValue = mv.mainValue LEFT JOIN
     table4 t4
     ON t4.mainValue = mv.mainValue;
```

In Oracle, you can also use the `USING` clause.